# Communication among two android devices connected over same/different WiFi networks/Mobile Data

Tags: android, communication, android-wifi, android-networking, mobile-devices

I need to develop an application through which TWO or MORE android devices can communicate with each other over same/different WiFi networks or using their mobile data. In short, no matter how they connect to internet, they should be able to communicate just like in whatsapp.

Could someone please guide me how this can be done?

Comment: I have tried this example http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com/2014/06/android-tcpip-client-server-socket.html.

But this is not working. I suppose that the problem is in the function getDeviceIpAddress().

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking. The simplest thing to do is to use a server as an intermediary. Is the problem that you don't know how to setup the server?

Comment: That is correct. I am new at android and I have been looking for such an implementation. Should a web service be used for this purpose on the server?